# When typing uppercase letter, Is it faster to press shift with same hand as the letter or there is no difference?

Tags: text, text-editor, typing

Are there any studies comparing typing speed of these styles of case shifting:

- use shift only on one side of keyboard. Use pinky+ corresponding
  finger when the letter is on the same side as the shift you use.
- use both sides and shift with the opposite hand.

Comment: What you might want to look into is [Keystroke-level model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke-level_model). I don't think anyone has studied in isolation how fast typing uppercase letters is.

Comment: A typist's choice of shift key is not necessarily just about speed. It may also be about being able to maintain the general flow of typing between the two available hands. You probably need to ask typists this question rather than UXers.

Comment: What is the particular user problem that you want to solve? Is it related to keyboard layout or some usability issue?